# Retrieving Jenkins node variables from master

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, slave

So my google-fu has failed me and the Jenkins O'Reilly book isn't helping either.

I have a Jenkins setup with a master and 20-odd nodes.  I make heavy use of custom environment variables on the nodes, as many of them perform similar tasks, only slightly different platforms.

I'm now in a position that I have a job that runs on the master (by necessity), which needs to know certain node properties for any given node, including some of the environment variables that I've set up.

Is there any way to reference these?  My alternative seems to be to have hundreds of environment variables in the master in the form node1_var1, node2_var1, node1_var2, node2_var2 etc., which just seems messy.  The master clearly has knowledge of the variables, as that's where the configuration for them is done, but I just can't find a way to specify them in a job.

Any help (or ridicule and pointing out of obvious answers) much appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple Groovy script that prints the list of environment variables for each slave:

```groovy
for (slave in jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.slaves) {
  println(slave.name + ": ")
  def props = slave.nodeProperties.getAll(hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.class)
  for (prop in props) {
    for (envvar in prop.envVars) {
      println envvar.key + " -> " + envvar.value
    }
  }
}
```

*Warning: I am not an experienced Groovy programmer, so I may not be using the appropriate idioms of Groovy.*

You can run this from the [Jenkins script console](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Script+Console) in order to experiment. You can also run a "System Groovy Script" as a build step. Both of the above require the [Groovy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin). If you don't use Groovy in your job, you could use this script to write a properties file that you load in the part of your build that does the real work.

Comment: Thanks.  I used a slightly different solution in the end, but groovy seemed to be the right direction to be looking in.  I used EnvInject with the following script:

`    import jenkins.model.*
    myEnvVars =  jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getNode("node1").getNodeProperties() [0].getEnvVars()
    def map = [ "nodeVar1" : myEnvVars.get( "nodeVar1" ) , "nodeVar2" : myEnvVars.get( "nodeVar2" ) ] ;
    return map ;`

Comment: @Tony, one note on your code, in my instance with various plugins and slave configuration, `nodeProperties[0]` did not always contain the node's environment variables -- thus the `getAll` call with the env var class.